# How to size a bitmap to the text to be shown in it?

Tags: c#, printing

I'm working on receipt printing using C# and WinForms. The problem is that after clicking the print button, it only prints the first item in the datagrid view and half of the second item, like this:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TS-POS.accdb");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Sales (InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate, Pname, Pprice, Bcode, Staff) VALUES ('" + txtInvoiceNo.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "', '" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + lblUser.Text + "')", conn);
       // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staff", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = lblUser.Text;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        conn.Close();

    }

    printready();

    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();

    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();

    if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
    {
        PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();

        pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pqr);

        pdoc.Print();
    }
}

void pqr(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image i = this.pictureBox1.Image;

    Point p = new Point(1, 1);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, p);
}

private void printready()
{ 
    string welcome = "Thank You For Visiting Dulabk";
    string InvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
    string InvoiceDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString();
    Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(welcome.Length * 30, 90);

    using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitm))
    {
        int startX = 0;
        int startY = 0;
        int Offset = 0;

        Font newfont = new Font("Arial Black", 8);
        Font newfont2 = new Font("Arial Black", 10);
        PointF point = new PointF(40f, 2f);
        SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        graphic.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitm.Width, bitm.Height);
        graphic.DrawString("" + InvoiceNo + "", newfont2, black, startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        PointF pointPrice = new PointF(15f, 45f);
        graphic.DrawString("" + InvoiceDate + "", newfont2, black, startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        PointF pointPname = new PointF(10f, 65f); 
        PointF pointBar = new PointF(10f, 65f);
        graphic.DrawString("" + welcome + "", newfont2, black, startX, startY + Offset);
        Offset = Offset + 20;
        PointF pointList = new PointF(10f, 65f); 

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int ii = 1;
            ii++;

            graphic.DrawString(" " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value +"  " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value +"  " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value +"" , new Font("Arial Bold", 11),
                     new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + Offset);
            Offset = Offset + 20;
            graphic.DrawString(" ---------- ", newfont2, black, startX, startY + Offset);
        }
    }

    using (MemoryStream Mmst = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitm.Save("ms", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        pictureBox1.Image = bitm;
        pictureBox1.Width = bitm.Width;
        pictureBox1.Height = bitm.Height;


    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing this: I have tried increasing offsets and adding more lines below the datagridview rows but nothing more is getting printed.

**EDIT**

Ok, I found the problem, it is in this line:

```
Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(welcome.Length * 30, 90);
```

How can I make the image size dynamic and not according to a value I set in the code?

Comment: Do you know how many lines are going to be printed? Do you know the height of each line?

Comment: No, the number of lines will be changed according to the number of products sold tho, so I can't know

Comment: Isma, I removed it

Comment: @JoeyArnanzo Could the number of lines to be printed be related to dataGridView1.Rows.Count?

Comment: @Joey Arnanzo, you can still include it, but add it as a link at the end of the question. Let me know if you don't know how..

Comment: Yes, I only saw the image and had to scroll to read the rest. I think a link to the image, a smaller one or including it at the end of the question  would make it much more readable. No?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah I guess it can be, other lines will be static number for the date, invoice number, total and such, so how can the row count be used in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable number of lines for the items and a fixed amount of supplementary information. You know how much vertical space you are going to use for each line, so you can calculate the size of the bitmap in advance.

Incidentally, the code uses a lot of resources which should be disposed of in addition to the `graphic` entity. You might want to use "using" on them instead of the way I did it in the following code. Also, there were some unused variables that I commented out.

So you could end up with code something like:

```
private void printready()
{
    string welcome = "Thank You For Visiting Dulabk";
    string InvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
    string InvoiceDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToLongDateString();

    int lineHeight = 20;
    int supplementaryLines = 9;

    Bitmap bitm = new Bitmap(welcome.Length * 30, (supplementaryLines + dataGridView1.Rows.Count) * lineHeight);

    using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bitm))
    {
        int startX = 0;
        int startY = 0;
        int offsetY = 0;
        Font newfont2 = null;
        Font itemFont = null;
        SolidBrush black = null;
        SolidBrush white = null;

        try
        {
            //Font newfont = new Font("Arial Black", 8);
             newfont2 = new Font("Arial Black", 10);
             itemFont = new Font("Arial Bold", 11);

             black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
             white = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

            //PointF point = new PointF(40f, 2f);

            graphic.FillRectangle(white, 0, 0, bitm.Width, bitm.Height);
            graphic.DrawString("" + InvoiceNo + "", newfont2, black, startX, startY + offsetY);
            offsetY = offsetY + lineHeight;

            //PointF pointPrice = new PointF(15f, 45f);
            graphic.DrawString("" + InvoiceDate + "", newfont2, black, startX, startY + offsetY);
            offsetY = offsetY + lineHeight;

            //PointF pointPname = new PointF(10f, 65f);
            //PointF pointBar = new PointF(10f, 65f);
            graphic.DrawString("" + welcome + "", newfont2, black, startX, startY + offsetY);
            offsetY = offsetY + lineHeight;

            PointF pointList = new PointF(10f, 65f);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int ii = 1;
                ii++;

                graphic.DrawString(" " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "  " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "  " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "", itemFont,
                         black, startX, startY + offsetY);
                offsetY = offsetY + lineHeight;
                graphic.DrawString(" ---------- ", newfont2, black, startX, startY + offsetY);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            black.Dispose();
            white.Dispose();
            itemFont.Dispose();
            newfont2.Dispose();
        }
    }

    using (MemoryStream Mmst = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitm.Save("ms", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        pictureBox1.Image = bitm;
        pictureBox1.Width = bitm.Width;
        pictureBox1.Height = bitm.Height;


    }

    bitm.Dispose();

}
```

Now there only remains the problem of what to do if a line exceeds `welcome.Length * 30`, but I suspect you can figure that out now.

Comment: @JoeyArnanzo You're welcome :) I edited your original question to put the image back in because that was essential to me being able to see what the answer would be.